# "Event not found" error for shell command in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, tcsh

when i am trying to remove  consecutive duplicate lines  with

`awk "!x[$0]++" file`

its reporting `x[: Event not found.`

even the same case with

`sed -i -e "$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P;D" file`   as well reporting

`N: Event not found.`
i tried with single quotes too, it didn't help

Any idea to fix those

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're invoking the shell's history substitution. Surround the exclamation point with single quotes.

Comment: Thanks so much, Working! when i tested this command in other system unix, it works correctly, what wrong with the shell!

Comment: one more thing when i tried to print `"Hello"` with `echo "\"Hello\"" `  in `tcsh` shellit saying `Unmatched ".` can you please fix this

Comment: Nope. Dunno tcsh, and I don't care to.

Comment: @user1228191: Once again, use single quotes: `echo '"Hello"'`

Comment: I'm surprised that worked. In tcsh, `echo "'!'hello"` prints `'!'hello`, and `echo '!hello'` prints `hello: Event not found.`. It's generally more reliable to escape `!` characters with backslashes. (csh/tcsh syntax is not consistent and typically requires either trial and error or a different shell.)