# Why grep is not working with regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, bash

I have a regular expression to find functions in files.

[See how expression perfectly works in PHP](https://regex101.com/r/cZ1pJ4/16)

If I try to run same regex with grep from console, I get an error:

```
grep -rP "(_t\s*\(\s*([\'\"])(\d+)\2\s*,\s*([\'\"])(.*?)(?<!\\)\4\s*(?(?=,)[^\)]*\s*\)|\)))" application scripts library public data | sort -n | uniq

grep: unrecognized character after (?<
```

Looks like `grep` can't handle this part of regex `(?<!\\)` , which is important for me.

Can anyone advise how to modify regex to make `grep` work with it?

EDIT:
    String: `_t('123', 'pcs.', '', $userLang)  . $data['ticker'] . ' (' . $data['security_name'] . ')`

Need to find:

1. index in function ('123')
2. text in function ('pcs.')
3. function itself

   ```
   > _t('123', 'pcs.', '', $userLang)
   ```

Comment: That's not a very nice regex, is it? As you've discovered, The `!` character is significant to the shell within double quotes. Personally I'd go down the route of enclosing the whole thing in single quotes and then using `'"'"'` for each single quote in the regex. Either way, it would be useful if you could make your question self-contained by showing us the pattern you are trying to match here.

Comment: Don't you need the `-e` flag for extended regexen?

Comment: Side note: the error you get is not thrown by `grep` but by Bash (look at the error: `-bash: !\: event not found`). An easy fix is to disable command history with `set +o history`.

Comment: when I run it from PHP with exec I still get error on that part "grep: missing )"

Comment: @collapsar that would be `-E` (at least on my grep) and here the OP is using `-P` with enables Perl regular expression (PCRE) support.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Event not found" error for shell command in unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221835/event-not-found-error-for-shell-command-in-unix)

Comment: @tripleee, it is not about events in shell, it's about regex in grep

Comment: @tripleee, I've edited error

Answer (score 3):

Doing what I said in the comments solves your problem (using the data from the link):

```
$ cat file
_t('123', 'шт.', '', $userLang)  . $data['ticker'] . ' (' . $data['security_name'] . ')
$ grep -P '(_t\s*\(\s*(['"'"'"])(\d+)\2\s*,\s*(['"'"'"])(.*?)(?<!\\)\4\s*(?(?=,)[^\)]*\s*\)|\)))' file
_t('123', 'шт.', '', $userLang)  . $data['ticker'] . ' (' . $data['security_name'] . ')
```

The trick here is to use single quotes around the whole regex, then whenever you want a single quote, do `'"'"'`, which means "close the original string, add a single quote within double quotes, then open a new single-quoted string". Another alternative, as proposed by [glglgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296974/glglgl#), would be to use `'\''`, i.e. close the original string, add an escaped `'` and open a new string.

Using single quotes prevents bash from interpreting the `!` as a history expansion. As [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) mentions above The other option would be to disable that behaviour, using `set +o history`.

Just as a suggestion, if you're looking to capture separate parts of the regex (and you're already using PCRE mode in grep), you could use Perl instead:

```
$ perl -lne '/(_t\s*\(\s*(['\''"])(\d+)\2\s*,\s*(['\''"])(.*?)(?<!\\)\4\s*(?(?=,)[^\)]*\s*\)|\)))/ && print "group 1: $1\ngroup 3: $3\n group 5: $5"' file
group 1: _t('123', 'шт.', '', $userLang)
group 3: 123
group 5: шт.
```

Comment: Alternative to `'"'"'` is `'\''`.

Comment: I might be missing something...
grep -rP "(_t\s*\(\s*(['"'"'"])(\d+)\2\s*,\s*(['"'"'"])(.*?)(?<\)\4\s*(?(?=,)[^\)]*\s*\)|\)))" application scripts library public data | sort -n | uniq

Comment: grep: unrecognized character after (?<

Comment: same error with single quotes...                    grep -rP '(_t\s*\(\s*(['"'"'"])(\d+)\2\s*,\s*(['"'"'"])(.*?)(?<\)\4\s*(?(?=,)[^\)]*\s*\)|\)))' application scripts library public data | sort -n | uniq

Comment: seems like trouble is not with [\'\"] part. The trouble is with (?<!\\) part of the regex. If I remove it, grep works fine with any combination of single and double quotes.

Comment: @Prosto In that case, I would suggest using Perl as I have shown. Does that work for you?

Comment: @TomFenech You are trying to emulate a stateful parser with a stateless regex. This cannot work reliably.

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm not saying it can, though perhaps I should be more explicit in stating that I don't endorse the approach. As far as I'm concerned, the original issue was a shell scripting one (especially when the question itself contained no sign of any PHP), hence my answer.

Comment: @TomFenech I never before used perl to search for text in file in multiple directories. Not sure what to start with.

Comment: @TomFenech Sure, I should have said "OP tries to emulate ..." However, I think there are many "funny" edge cases like `$string = "\'function_call()\'";` or whatever complexity you can imagine of. A regex can't provide unlimited complexity.

Comment: @Prosto I'm sorry but that is really beyond the scope of the original question. Your regex is working now, at least in a version of grep that supports PCRE mode. To search in multiple files, you will have to pass all of their names to Perl. How exactly you go about doing that depends on your shell and your directory structure at a mininum.

Comment: The double quotes also explain the unmatched parentesis error and related errors; within double quotes, `\\)` gets reduced to `\)`.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use the [tokenizer extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) in order to parse PHP files. This is because parsing a programming language requires a stateful parser, a single regex is stateless and therefore cannot provide this.

Here comes an example how to extract function names from a PHP source file, tracking function calls is possible as well:

```
$source = file_get_contents('some.php');

$tokens = token_get_all($source);
for($i = 0; $i < count($tokens); $i++) {
    $token = $tokens[$i];
    if(!is_string($token)) {
        if($token[0] === T_FUNCTION) {
            // skip whitespace between the keyword 'function' 
            // and the function's name
            $i+=2;
            // Avoid to print the opening brackets of a closure
            if($tokens[$i][0] === T_STRING) {
                echo $tokens[$i][1] . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

In comments you told that you also want to parse html, js files. I recommend a DOM/JS parser for that.

Comment: I parse js and html files also

Comment: I was about to create an example. However, if you want to parse js files as well, then the tokenizer extensions isn't an option here

Comment: I ca parse all files with php. It's not a problem. Problem is perfomance. Grep does it thousands times faster (I have several thousands files to parse)